# Unexpected value 'AngularFireDatabase' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angularfire2

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

imports: [    
    AngularFireDatabase
]
```

For some reason it keep's asking for me to add a @NgModule annotation when I don't need one. I am fairly new to Firebase.

I have tried adding this to my **tsconfig.json** file to see if it can pick up the angularfire2 modules but still no luck:

```
"paths": {
  "@angular/*": [
    "../node_modules/@angular/*"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get rid of the error by using the following in my index.html:

```
    <script src="/__/firebase/4.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/4.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/4.6.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="/__/firebase/4.6.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what you need in the *app.module.ts* in order to use that module.

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

// you may need this at some point if you do not have it already
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2'; 

...
imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(<config>),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule 
]
...
```

[Information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) about the product and configuration.

Another detailed [resource](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/54/Angular-4-Firebase-Tutorial:-Make-a-Simple-Angular-4-App).

Comment: I had the above code in, and added what you suggested but still the same result, I've checked all the information on https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I do "import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'firebase2/database'"
in app module class and "import {AngularFireDatabase} from 'firebase2/database'in app.component.ts problem get resolved.
Don't use both in the same class -> app module and any .ts file in which you are doing firebase database work.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks for the suggestion ^_^